# Decorating Java's callable to add behavior

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, threadpool, callable

Let's assume we have potentially long-running task:

```
public class LongRunningTask {
    public ReturnType doSomething() {
        ...
    }
}
```

and that we want to run many of these tasks concurrently.

So, I have my callable for it:

```
public class LongRunningCallable implements Callable<LongRunningTask> {
    private final LongRunningTask task;
    ...
    public ReturnType call() {
        return task.doSomething();
    }
    ...
}
```

Now, since that might really last long, I minght want to limit it to run for certain amount only. So, I might do something like this:

```
public class InterruptibleCallable<T> implements Callable<T> {
        protected final long timeout;
        protected final TimeUnit timeUnit;
        protected final Callable<T> callable;

        public InterruptibleCallable(long timeout, TimeUnit timeUnit, Callable<T> callable) {
                this.timeout = timeout;
                this.timeUnit = timeUnit;
                this.callable = callable;
        }

        @Override
        public T call() throws Exception {

                ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

                T result = null;

                try {
                    result = executorService.submit(callable).get(timeout, timeUnit);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    LOGGER.error("Callable: " + callable.toString() + " was interrupted");
                    throw e;
                } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                    throw e;
                } catch (TimeoutException e) {
                    LOGGER.warn("Callable: " + callable.toString() + " timed out after " + timeout + " " + timeUnit);
                    throw e;
                } finally {
                    executorService.shutdown();
                }

                return result;
        }
}
```

And that is OK, but now I'd also like to wrap it so it can retry itself (with delay) if it encounteres an exception:

```
public class RetryableCallable<T> implements Callable<T> {
    private final long delay;
    private final TimeUnit timeUnit;
    private final Callable<T> callable;

    @Override
    public T call() throws Exception {
        T result = null;

        try {
            ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
            result = executorService.submit(this.callable).get();
        } catch (Exception e) {         
            ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
            result = executorService.schedule(this.callable, delay, timeUnit).get();
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Now, my question(s):

1. Is there already a library that provides this (or a superset) of this capabilites?
2. Is this a good design, especially creating another executor and submitting a callable in each wrapper and why?
3. What is the best way to approach this problem, from both design pattern view and performance view?

Thank you :D

Comment: Why would you want a class that has "callable" in its name to create a new thread pool?  That sounds way too complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap `RetryableCallable` around `InterruptibleCallable` which wraps `LongRunningTask` and create two extra executors on each `RetryableCallable` execution is bad.

When `RetryableCallable` catches `TimeoutException` usually it shouldn't run same task again. It's kind of confusing, because if task was "killed" by timeout why do you want to run it one more time?
Also why do you need to create another executor here? Keep it simple

```
public class RetryableCallable<T> implements Callable<T> {
    private int retries = 3;

    @Override
    public T call() throws Exception {
        while (retries-- > 0) {
            try {
                return callable.call();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                LOGGER.error("Callable: " + callable.toString() + " was interrupted");
                throw e;
            } catch (TimeoutException e) {
                LOGGER.warn("Callable: " + callable.toString() + " timed out after " + timeout + " " + timeUnit);
                throw e;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOGGER.warn("Callable: " + callable.toString() + " failed");
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalStateException();//or return null
    }
}
```

And it shouldn't use timeouts and delays, it's `RetryableCallable` but not a `RetryableCallableWithDelayAndTimeoutAndSomethingElse`

If you want to limit task's execution time I see at least 4 good ways to do it:

- call `get(time, timeunit)` in thread which submitted it
- limit task's execution time inside a `call()` function, e.g. by checking "periodically" do we have some more time.
- make your own executor class with custom executor inside it and one thread Auditor, which would accept some `TimeLimitedCallable` which extends `Callable` and has `int getTimeLimit()` function. Auditor would control time bounds of all running tasks implementing `TimeLimitedCallable`.
- making a separate executor for "task's auditors" and after submitting one (or bunch) of tasks with business logic into main executor - create and submit auditor task into separate executor.